# moving items inside constraint layout cardview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-constraintlayout

This is my layout I am using for a activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.phocast.AboutMeActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_abtme"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bgcol_abtme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.883">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="120sp"
            android:layout_height="120sp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_face_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1_abtme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_abtme"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/about_icon_facebook" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="12sp"
            android:text="@string/facebook_id"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_abtme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:text="@string/user_name"
         android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

   ....   
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The output looks like:
[image]

The problem is I can't move the items inside the cardview either programatically or using drag in design view of android studio.

Like, for say, I want to have

1. Imageview `iv1_abtme`(the facebook icon) below the `tv_abtme`
2. `textview4` horizentally aligned to `iv1_abtme` 
   etc.

Can anyone kindly help me on what is going wrong here(why I cant simply drag items)

Answer (score 0):

[`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) is based on a [`FrameLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and the documentation there clearly says:

> Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

So, to solve your problem, your `CardView` needs to have a single child that is a view group for your views, such as `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, or `ConstraintLayout`.